# ggplot2 how to draw arbitrary diagonal lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
mtcars %>%
ggplot(aes(hp,displ))+
geom_point()+
geom_point(x=100,y=300,col="red",shape=10,size=10)
```

How do I draw a diagonal line connecting the points y axis intercept = 300 and x axis intercept = 100?

`geom_abline` and `geom_segment` fail to do the job. I need to be able to specify where the line starts and ends.

Comment: What goes wrong with `geom_segment`? It should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to add a geom that's not related to a data frame, `annotate` is often a good way:

```
mtcars %>%
ggplot(aes(hp,disp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(x=100,y=300,col="red",shape=10,size=10) +
  annotate(geom = "segment", x = 0, y = 300, xend = 100, yend = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to create a helper data frame and use `geom_line()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

df_line <- data.frame(x = c(0, 200),
                      y = c(300, 0))

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(hp, disp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(x=100,y=300,col="red",shape=10,size=10)+
  geom_line(data = df_line, aes(x, y), colour = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

`geom_abline()` works too, slightly different effect in that the line extends beyond the stated limits:

```r
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(hp, disp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(x=100,y=300,col="red",shape=10,size=10)+
  geom_abline(slope = - 3/2, intercept = 300, colour = "red")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 400), ylim = c(0, 500))
```

[image]